# squish a button with border-radius ellipsis

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I'm making a button for my 4 year old. 2 `div`s, css `border-radius:`, and jquery `.animate`. I've used percentage `border-radius` to get a nice elliptical shape.

Everything's working okay so far, except that when the button is "depressed" I need to shorten the underneath part of the button. This is to hide the corners of the div. When I shorten the div, however, the curve of the ellipsis "squishes". It's subtle, I don't think my kid will notice, but I do.

My question is two-fold: 
How do I solve this squishing issue?
Why does this produce a not-the-ellipse I'm looking for:

```
border-bottom-right-radius: 100px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 100px;
```

The pen: http://codepen.io/claytron5000/pen/PqqNya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It produces the issue because the percentage based height is based on the width and height, so when you change the height, the percentage radius changes. This is how you achieve the ellipse in the first place.  I have solved the issue here by manipulating a third div, inbetween the two, and having an ellipse above and below, and then animating `margin-top` and `height` of the middle div only (and leaving the top ellipse animation alone).

Here is a codepen of the solution: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOONXm

To answer your second question, the values of 100px don't work the way you want them to, because that (`border-bottom-right-radius: 100px;`) is shorthand for setting both height and width values (`border-bottom-right-radius: 100px 100px;`). If you want to usa a pixel value, use

```
border-bottom-right-radius: 150px 100px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 150px 100px;
```

Which in this case is equivalent to

```
 border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
```

Because your width is 300px and height is 200px